# TypeError (python tkinter Entry)

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror, tkinter-entry

```
from tkinter import *

app=Tk()
app.title("progress")
app.geometry("800x500+365+120")

q={'weigh':100,'goal':75,'now':86} #or 'now':93

def bar():
    first=int(q['weigh'])
    achieve=int(q['goal'])
    today=int(q['now'])

    def num(n):
        for z in range(0,n):
            y=(first-achieve)*(z/100)
            if (first-today)==y:
                return z
            if today<achieve:
                z=100
                return z
    rate=int(num(101)/10)
    for _ in range(1,rate+1):
        Entry(app,bg="blue",width=4).pack(side=LEFT)
    for _ in range(rate,10):
        Entry(app,width=4).pack(side=LEFT)

Button(app,text="OK",command=bar).pack()
app.mainloop()
```

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I make progress bar.
But this does not work only when q['now'] is 86 or 93.
Why does this Error occur and how can I solve it?

Comment: Is there the possibility of `num` not returning anything? If so your error might come from `num(101)/10`. Also please post the full error traceback

Comment: What should be returned after the for loop inside `num()`?

Comment: @TheLizzard Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KMS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\KMS\Desktop\aaaa.py", line 24, in bar
    rate=int(num(101)/10)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: @hyem_msg So it is as I guessed. `num(101)` doesn't return anything because the if statements aren't satisfied. So the function automatically returns `None` which you are trying to divide by `10`. That raises the error

Comment: @TheLizzard all number except 86,93 works well. then I want to use 86 and 93, what should I do?

Comment: @hyem_msg I have no idea how your program works but it seems to me like those if statements have broken logic. Try rewriting that part of your code.

Comment: It is because you are comparing float number (`y`) and integer number (`first-today`).  When I print the values when `z` is 56, I get `14.000000000000002` for `y` and `14` for `first-today`.  Your code should expect they are equal, but the result is not.  Use `y=round((first-achieve)*(z/100), 2)`.

Comment: @acw1668 WOW! Thanks to you, I solve this error! Thank you very much! Everything you do will be fine!

Answer (score 0):

this is normal problem:

The normal function is returned None. so this mean in your `for loop` in `num(n)` function the if you made isn't true so the functions doesn't return `z` it's returned as normal function which is `None`. so if you want to check that append `else` and print out if the if statements doesn't true. like this :

```py
    def num(n):
        for z in range(0,n):
            y=(first-achieve)*(z/100)
            if (first-today)==y:
                return z
            if today<achieve:
                z=100
                return z
            else:
                print('The if statements is not true so the function now returned None')
```

so if you want to return the z in all statements in `else` append `return z` so when you call the function every where and every time it's will return `int` do:

```py
    def num(n):
        for z in range(0,n):
            y=(first-achieve)*(z/100)
            if (first-today)==y:
                return z
            if today<achieve:
                z=100
                return z
            else:
                return z 
                # if you want to give a message error to user do this:
                # from tkinter import messagebox
                # messagebox.showerror('Error', 'the function dosen't returned int')
```

the final code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter

app=Tk()
app.title("progress")
app.geometry("800x500+365+120")

q={'weigh':100,'goal':75,'now':86} #or 'now':93

def bar():
    first=int(q['weigh'])
    achieve=int(q['goal'])
    today=int(q['now'])

    def num(n):
        for z in range(0,n):
            y=(first-achieve)*(z/100)
            if (first-today)==y:
                return z
            if today<achieve:
                z=100
                return z
            else:
                return z 
                # if you want to give a message error to user do this:
                # from tkinter import messagebox
                # messagebox.showerror('Error', 'the function dosen't returned int')
                
    print(num(101))
    rate=int(num(101)/10)
    for _ in range(1,rate+1):
        Entry(app,bg="blue",width=4).pack(side=LEFT)
    for _ in range(rate,10):
        Entry(app,width=4).pack(side=LEFT)

Button(app,text="OK",command=bar).pack()
app.mainloop()
```

Hope this works.

Comment: @ShihabAl-den From what you did, the for loop will only run once with `z = 0` then it will stop. I think that it will be better if you moved the last `return z` just after the for loop.

Comment: @ShihabAl-den sorry my friend.

Comment: yes but maybe he want some other Conditions @TheLizzard